# Recursive Sum of each level in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, recursive-query, sql-server-2017

I need to find out the recursive sum of each node of a tree. Please find the image below.

Here the number(assuming no of sales made) in blue is the sum of Parent Quantity + Sum of its children and number in red is sale made by node itself . So if we take example of **Node C = 44** , then its calculation is something like this.

**Node C** has a child **F** and **F** has again two children **G** and **H**. **G & H** got no children. But they made **5 and 6** number of sales respectively. Also their Parent **F** too made **11 sales on his own**, so **total sales of F will be 22 [ 11 his own and 11 from his children]**. Also in the same line **C**, the parent of **F** , also got **22 sales** of his own. So now total number of sales made by **C** will be **44** (**his own 22**  and **22 from his child and grand children**).

And this hierarchy and calculation will go on. There's no restriction in depth and breadth of hierarchy as well. A node can have N number of children.

[image]

My database has 3 tables as shown in this screenshot:

[image: FIG-2]

- **StoreMaster**: this table contains a master list of all stores.
- **StoreMaps**: this is a mapping table which maintains the parent child hierarchies. Here `MasterStoreId -> ParentId` and `SlaveStoreId -> ChildId`. Both masterstoreid and slavestoreid references to storeid of the `StoreMaster` table. Also, this maps table supports N level of children in any hierarchy. There's no restrictions at all.
- **StoreSales**: transaction table for StoreMaster. This table contains store specific sales.

What I want to achieve is that I need a recursive query that will help finding me `TotalAmount` and `Quantity of Sales` made by each and every store as shown in figure 1 [above].

I tried using CTE but not getting the desired output. Here's what I tried

```
;WITH ChildStores AS 
(
    SELECT SlaveStoreId
    FROM StoreMaps
    WHERE SlaveStoreId = 35
        
    UNION ALL
        
    SELECT t.SlaveStoreId
    FROM StoreMaps t
    INNER JOIN ChildStores r ON t.MasterStoreId = r.SlaveStoreId
)
INSERT INTO @StoreTable
    SELECT *
    FROM ChildStores

SELECT DISTINCT ss.StoreId, ss.StoreCode, ss.StoreName  
FROM StoreSales ss 
WHERE ss.StoreId IN (SELECT * FROM @StoreTable)

SELECT ss.StoreName, COUNT(ss.SaleId), SUM(ss.AmountPaid) 
FROM StoreSales ss 
WHERE ss.StoreId IN (SELECT * FROM @StoreTable)  
  AND ss.SaleStatus = 'Paid' 
  AND ss.PlanCode <> '12345'
GROUP BY ss.StoreName
```

Second query:

```
WITH cteAggregateCost AS 
(  
    SELECT 
        i.SlaveStoreId AS rootid, i.SlaveStoreId, i.MasterStoreId
    FROM
        StoreMaps  i 

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        rootid, i.SlaveStoreId, i.MasterStoreId
    FROM
        StoreMaps i 
    JOIN
        cteAggregateCost c ON i.MasterStoreId = c.SlaveStoreId
)
SELECT
    t.StoreName, SUM(t.AmountPaid) AS AggregateCost
FROM
    StoreMaps a
LEFT JOIN
    cteAggregateCost i ON a.SlaveStoreId = i.rootid 
LEFT JOIN 
    StoreSales t ON i.SlaveStoreId = t.StoreId
WHERE 
    t.SaleStatus = 'Paid' 
    AND t.PlanCode <> 12345
GROUP BY
    t.StoreName
```

Schema

```
CREATE TABLE StoreMaps
(
    [StoreMapId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MasterStoreId] [int] NULL,
    [MasterStoreCode] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [SlaveStoreId] [int] NULL,
    [SlaveStoreCode] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_StoreMaps] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([StoreMapId] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE StoreMaster
(
    [StoreId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StoreName] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [StoreCode] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
    
    CONSTRAINT [PK_StoreMaster] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([StoreId] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE StoreSales
(
    [SaleId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StoreId] [int] NULL,
    [StoreCode] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [StoreName] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [SaleStatus] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [AmountPaid] [int] NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_StoreSales] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SaleId] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,  
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Full query

```
DECLARE @StoreCode VARCHAR(10) = NULL, 
        @StartDate DATE = NULL, @EndDate DATE = NULL

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Description VARCHAR(50), 
        @NetSales DECIMAL(16, 2), 
        @Quantity TINYINT, 
        @PayoutPercent TINYINT, @PayableAmount DECIMAL(16, 2), 
        @StoreName VARCHAR(150), @PartnerId TINYINT, 
        @Rowcount INT, @BillingMonth VARCHAR(10)

DECLARE @StoreTable AS TABLE (StoreId INT);

--INSERT INTO SpDebug (ObjectName, ObjectParam)
--VALUES (OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID), @JsonParams)
IF ISNULL(TRIM(@StoreCode), '') = ''
BEGIN
    SET @StoreCode = 'GW'
END

IF ISNULL(@StartDate, '') = ''
BEGIN
    SET @StartDate = DATEADD(DD, - 7, GETDATE());
END

IF ISNULL(@EndDate, '') = ''
BEGIN
    --Select * from @StoreTable
    SET @EndDate = DATEADD(dd, - 1, GETDATE());
END

BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    WITH ChildStores
    AS (
        SELECT SlaveStoreId
        FROM StoreMaps
        WHERE SlaveStoreCode = @StoreCode
        
        UNION ALL
        
        SELECT t.SlaveStoreId
        FROM StoreMaps t
        INNER JOIN ChildStores r
            ON t.MasterStoreId = r.SlaveStoreId
        )
    INSERT INTO @StoreTable
    SELECT *
    FROM ChildStores

    SELECT @Rowcount = COUNT(*)
    FROM @StoreTable;

    WHILE (@Rowcount > 0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @Rowcount = @Rowcount - 1;

        SELECT @PartnerId = StoreId
        FROM @StoreTable
        ORDER BY StoreId DESC OFFSET @Rowcount ROWS

        FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;

        IF EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM StoreMaster
                WHERE StoreId = @PartnerId
                    AND IsActive = 1
                    AND ExcludeFromPayout = 0
                )
        BEGIN
            SELECT @PayoutPercent = PayoutPercent, @StoreName = StoreName, @StoreCode = StoreCode
            FROM StoreMaster
            WHERE StoreId = @PartnerId
            

            SET @Description = CONCAT ('Payout for ', FORMAT(@StartDate, 'dd-MMM-yyyy'), ' & ', FORMAT(@EndDate, 'dd-MMM-yyyy'));

            SELECT @Quantity = COUNT(SaleId), @NetSales = SUM(AmountPaid / 1.18)
            FROM StoreSales
            WHERE StoreId = @PartnerId
                AND (
                    CAST(ModifiedOn AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST(@StartDate AS DATE)
                        AND CAST(@EndDate AS DATE)
                    )
                AND SaleStatus = 'Paid'
                AND PlanCode <> '12345'

            IF NOT EXISTS (
                    SELECT *
                    FROM PartnerInvoices
                    WHERE (
                            (
                                @StartDate BETWEEN PayoutStartDate
                                    AND PayoutEndDate
                                )
                            OR (
                                @EndDate BETWEEN PayoutStartDate
                                    AND PayoutEndDate
                                )
                            )
                        AND PartnerId = @PartnerId
                    )
            BEGIN
                SET @Quantity = ISNULL(@Quantity, 0)
                SET @NetSales = ISNULL(@NetSales, 0)
                SET @PayableAmount = ISNULL((@NetSales * @PayoutPercent * 0.01), 0)
                SET @BillingMonth = FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'MMyyyy')

                INSERT INTO PartnerInvoices (PartnerId, StoreName, PayoutStartDate, PayoutEndDate, BillingMonth, TxnRefNumber, [Description], NetSales, Quantity, PayoutPercent, PayableAmount)
                VALUES (@PartnerId, @StoreName, @StartDate, @EndDate, @BillingMonth, '', @Description, @NetSales, @Quantity, @PayoutPercent, @PayableAmount)
            END
                    --ELSE
                    --BEGIN
                    --  PRINT 'Invoice already generated for this duration.';
                    --END
        END
    END

    COMMIT TRANSACTION

    SELECT 1;
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

    INSERT INTO AppErrors (ErrorMessage, ObjectName, [Parameters])
    VALUES (ERROR_MESSAGE(), OBJECT_NAME(@@procid), @PartnerId);

    THROW
END CATCH
```

Please help me fixing this query as this is a for extracting our channel partners payout and i cant spend much time in having R&D. This is a critical bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is something like this what you're looking for?

```sql
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT NULL AS MasterID, @MasterStoreID AS SlaveID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT M.MasterStoreId, M.SlaveStoreId AS SlaveID
    FROM CTE C
        INNER   JOIN StoreMaps M ON M.MasterStoreId = C.SlaveID
)
SELECT @MasterStoreID AS StoreID, SUM(ISNULL(S.AmountPaid, 0)) AS AmountPaidTotal
FROM CTE C
    LEFT    JOIN StoreSales S ON S.StoreId = C.SlaveID;
```

Where `@MasterStoreID` is the ID of the store you want the total sales of.

Edit:
This query will return `AmountPaid` sum for every store in `StoreMaster` table, without the `@MasterStoreID` parameter:

```sql
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT StoreID AS RootID, NULL AS MasterID, StoreID AS SlaveID
    FROM StoreMaster
    UNION ALL
    SELECT C.RootID, M.MasterStoreid, M.SlaveStoreId AS SlaveID
    FROM CTE C
        INNER   JOIN StoreMaps M ON M.MasterStoreid = C.SlaveID
)
SELECT C.RootID AS StoreID, SUM(ISNULL(S.AmountPaid, 0)) AS AmountPaidTotal
FROM CTE C
    LEFT    JOIN StoreSales S ON S.StoreId = C.SlaveID
GROUP BY C.RootID;
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, tweaking first query a little bit gave what i was expecting. Thanks again.